# How to resolve `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException` in Android Studio v4.2

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-studio-4.2

Getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException` after upgrading Android studio to `v4.2`

Everything was fine in `v4.1.3` and this started after update.

It ends with `Compilation with Kotlin compile daemon was not successful` error.

Answer (score -1):

Update the Gradle Wrapper. Could be it.

Comment: Tried this but no use. Still getting the same issue.